# I'm using qpython on my mobile and I'm trying to import a .py file but it's not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, mobile, syntax-error, sys

import sys
Print(sys.path)
I get a directory and try to put my .py file inside then I try to
Import filename
Then I get a syntax error telling me that filename is not defined...
I even tried to append a different path to sys but that doesnt work either

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code, as well as the error message? I'm not sure what exactly your question is asking.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/MF4Yyxh I'm trying to import my file named practice.py. I put it in those paths the print(sys.path) told me and even appending a new path but it will not import my file practice.py.... the picture is of the error message and the paths the console gives me. I just want to import my file

Comment: Where is `practice.py` located?